# How can I make MySQL database accessible from other networks?

Tags: mysql

I created a MySQL database using wampserver64 from the user root, I've researched about how to make it accessible for other people and I was told to make a new user (because I had my database in root) and grant all the permissions, the new user I created works, but I only can see my database from my computer. When I try to open it in another computer connected to a different network I get multiple PHP errors because "access is denied", I need to see my database table and manage it from different networks, how can I do this? Is this even possible? I'm really lost.

Comment: where is your mysql database | (your pc/your server) ?

Comment: it's on my pc, i made it a localhost database

Comment: From which network you want to access it | (local network/outside your network) ?

Comment: @vaku outside my network

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL a user is identified by a username and a scope: `user@localhost` and `user@someotherhost` are not the same user and may have different privileges. To assign privileges to a user independent on from which host he connects, use `user@%` (`%` is the wildcard in SQL, similar to `*` for a file system).

Most likely you have created your user only as `user@localhost`, which will create just the behaviour you ave observed.

To allow a user access to a DB via the network (from any IP address) use

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON databasename.* TO username@`%` IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Comment: ok, after i do that, am i able to access to the database table on another network through the user I created in wampserver's phpmyadmin? or wampserver only works when it's local?

Comment: PHPmyAdmin is just another user interface. You should no longer get "Access denied" after running the `GRANT` from above, no matter if you do so via CLI or PHP,yAdmin.

Comment: sorry for the delay, but it says that I have a syntax error... it's mysql 8.0

Comment: It was a typo: not `GRANT on` but `GRANT all` - sorry for that